# IOS problem for share generator lnkedin link

Tags: hyperlink

'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url='
this share generator link is working for LinkedIn app in android and IOS correctly but in IOS when I just click on post in the LinkedIn app without any caption.I can't post.Can you help me on this??

expecting the solution.